# Angular ui: bootstrap datepicket input validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I'm using this [datepicker](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/datepicker). As of now, the user can write anything he likes in the input field which is not what I want.

My code:

session.js

```
  session.getDateFormat = function() {
            return 'yyyy-MM-dd';
        };

        session.formatDate = function(date) {
            return $filter('date')(date, session.getDateFormat());
        };
```

Controller.js

```
vm.dateFormat = session.getDateFormat();
function submit() {
date : session.formatDate(vm.data.date)
 }
```

The code is much longer but that basically the part concerning the date. And HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{vm.dateFormat}}" placeholder="{{vm.dateFormat}}" ng-model="vm.data.date" is-open="vm.dateOpened" ng-required="true" ng-disabled="disabled" />
```

The admin can choose if he wants getDateFormat to accept `yyyy-mm-dd` or `dd-mm-yyyy` etc.

What I want:

1. To verify that the user has input the date is the right format, otherwise to clear the field automatically and display an error message along with the right date format as a hint to the user. All that must be done before pressing submit.
2. Not allowing the user to enter letters obviously
3. No hard coded html regex, I want something to check if the input is the same as getDateFormat, otherwise clear the field and display an error.
4. No Jquery, I don't use Jquery in the entire project.
5. If you have any other datepicker in mind that works with angular and bootstrap without using Jquery, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to update to angular-ui 1.3.3 and then I had to give the date input a name 'datepicker' and the form a name 'frm' and then

```
<div ng-if="!frm.datepicker.$error.required"">
<div class="datepicker-error" ng-if="frm.datepicker.$invalid">
some error message
</div></div>
```

I didn't clear the field since if the user didn't finish typing it's going to be invalid and hence might be cleared. If anyone has a better solution let me know.

Comment: I'll accept my answer for now, if someone has a better answer, i'll accept his answer